# What's the Stellaris Apocalypse technology tree?

Tags: stellaris

Like in the title said whats the Stellaris Apocalypse technology tree? I have been playing it for half a week now but there is no end to it.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to ask, but I'll try to clarify what I can.

Apocalypse is a paid expansion that was released along with Stellaris v2.0 .

Stellaris v2.0 expanded the existing tech tree.  Consult the [Stellaris Wiki](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Stellaris_Wiki) or the [Stellaris Tech Tree](https://bipedalshark.gitlab.io/stellaris-tech-tree/vanilla/) for details.

Apocalypse includes a small number of extra techs for long range starbase weapons, planet killers, and titanic ships.  I think it's fair to say that we can expect these technologies to be Tier 5, and to be as unlikely to show up as a research option as any T5 tech.  The best you can do to increase your chances of seeing them is to get as many lower tier techs out of the way as quickly as possible.  You can also boost chances of a tech by having a matching researcher active when completing a research task.  I think it's fair to say that Voidcraft & Particle specialties should be helpful here.

---

**Edit** After checking the Wiki, it looks like the applicable techs are in the Physics & Engineering trees, and mostly benefit from a specialization in Voidcraft.

---

**v2.2**: I've found a nice 2.2 tech tree at [Stellaris Tech Tree](https://turanar.github.io/stellaris-tech-tree/vanilla/)

Answer (score 5):

In Stellaris, there isn't a predefined tech tree that you have to follow through the game like in the Civilization series for example. Instead, the techs that you can research are randomly selected from the available techs (from the [*official Stellaris wiki*](https://stellaris.paradoxwikis.com/Technology)):

> The user interaction aspect utilizes a card shuffle approach rather
>   than a traditional tech tree presentation, thereby introducing an
>   element of semi-randomness into the system.

I think you might be interested in this website: [sit.milaq.net](http://sit.milaq.net/#)

[image]

It is an interactive tech viewer for Stellaris, where you can view all the different techs in the game, and for each tech you can:

- details about the tech, such as the cost, tier, modifiers, effects, ...
- the type of tech
- the requirements for that tech
- the techs that can be unlocked with that tech

Comment: Nice site.  Shame that it's stalled at Stellaris v1.1

Comment: @tjd still thought it was worth posting even though it is out of date so he could better understand how techs work